# Run the test every 30 minutes everyday, 365 times per year

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using **selenium webdriver in java language and I add testNG** framework to be more efficiency in UAT test.

I need to run my tests every 30 minutes, every day, 365 times each year.

So every 48 tests/day, it means 17520 times each year (365*48 test per day)

My question is: which "method", "class", "or code..." in selenium webdriver or at least java, can I use to set up this frequency of tests?

Thank you all of you for helping me.

Regards, 
RBO

Comment: Set up a cron job

Comment: cron job or Jenkins

Comment: Also, don't say 365 days a year, unless you want to exclude February 29'th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Indeed it was a smart step integrating `TestNG` to your framework where you are using selenium webdriver in Java language.

Now when you say `I need to run my tests every 30 minutes, every day, 365 times each year` that essentially means there are frequent code/script changes & integration in your framework and you want to test it. This is called **Continous Integration**.

As by now you are already familiar with `Java Framework` and `TestNG` you are just a step away from making the arrangements for `Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery Toolchain`. Thats where **[Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)** comes to your help.

**Jenkins** is a self-contained, open source automation server which can be used to automate all sorts of tasks such as building, testing, and deploying software. Jenkins can be installed through native system packages or even run standalone by any machine with the Java Runtime Environment installed.

**Recommended Requirements**:

Jenkins distribution requires a minimum of Java 7, though Java 8 is recommended. A system with more than 512MB of RAM is also recommended.

**Steps to Integrate**:

1. [Download Jenkins](http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war).
2. Open up a terminal in the download directory and run **java -jar jenkins.war**
3. Browse to http://localhost:8080 and follow the instructions to complete the installation.

Incase you are familiar with executing the TestNG Tests through command-line, configuring Jenkins to run your Tests is a minutes task.

You can find the **[Detailed Documentation of Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/)** here.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure something called a CI (= continous integration). Examples of CI software are [Travis-ci](http://travis-ci.org/), [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) or [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). I use travis for my personal projects and at work, we use TeamCity. The CI software can then be configured to run the tests on a regular basis like every hour or every time you push to the repository.

The reason why you can't do this in a class or method is that starting a test run needs to be done using an external command, like the play button in your IDE or a command line command, like the CI uses. You could also use some other software like [EventGhost](http://www.eventghost.net/) and set up a timer there, but then you would need to have your computer running 24/7 and things will get very messy very soon. A CI like travis takes care of all of this for you (They spawn a new VM for every test run, they keep a history of test results, ...), the only thing you need to do is to configure it once and then write your Selenium tests as you did before :)